# Scheme - Removing duplicates from nested lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having trouble trying to remove duplicate elements from a set of nested lists. I know how to remove duplicates if the elements are in the same list. I just need to get put in the right direction. I'm starting from scratch again

For example, (rmdup '(a (b (a (c))))) should have the output (a (b (c)))

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can help out

Answer (score 0):

So far I have something like this:

```
(define (removeDups L)
  (if (null? L) '()
      (cons (car L) (removeDups (deepRemove (car L) (cdr L))))))
```

;Helper function for RemoveDups

```
(define (deepRemove n L)
  (if (null? L) '()
  (if (list? (car L))
      (cons (deepRemove n (car L)) (deepRemove n (cdr L)))
      (if (equal? n (car L))(deepRemove n (cdr L))
          (cons (car L)(deepRemove n (cdr L)))))))
```

Comment: By using the function removeDups above, it will only remove duplicated elements from each list, if it is the first element that has a duplicate. For instance, (removeDups '("cheese" ("sauce" ("cheese")))) returns ("cheese" ("sauce" ()))

Comment: But if you try (removeDups '("cheese" ("sauce" ("sauce")))) it returns the same exact list and doesn't remove sauce.